# Creating a header NIB and show on all Views

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, nib

This is what I want to achieve on an iPad app. I have a header which contains the company logo and few buttons at the top. This should appear on all the views or screens. But the buttons or logo changes frequently in the header. So, I have created a NIB with a controller named HeaderViewController. Now, I want to include this header nib file in all the views and main nib file. I want to add this using Interface builder.

Any kind of guidance is much appreciated. Also, let me know if there is any better approach to handle this. I am new to iOS development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create One `BaseClass` and where ever you want to show your header Create New Class which will be Sub Class of Your `BaseClass`. Means after creating `BaseClass` you need to do like this.

```
@interface YourClassName : BaseClass
```